# In Polymer Dart, how to build a CSS table using 1 polymer-element for the table and another for the rows and cells

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

My goal is to build a table using CSS (display:table, table-row, table-cell) with 1 custom polymer-element defining the div for the table, and another polymer-element defining the divs for the rows and cells, like this

```
<my-table>
  <my-row col1="contents of column 1" col2="column 2">
      --html for content of column 3--  
  </my-row>
</my-table>
```

The problem I'm having is that the div created by  with the "display:table;" isn't being recognized by the divs created by  with the "display:table-row" and "display:table-cell".  The divs created by  seem to think they are in their own individual tables.

Is there a way to get this to work?  If the answer is to use ::content ::shadow, then I need to be shown how because I can't get it to work and behave as a single large table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should style the `host` of the polymer element, not the divs inside it.

Here is an example: https://gist.github.com/jakemac53/0d073615d723502a61ca

Comment: Aaaah!  This has helped a lot.  Thanks!